# Conditions for the SDE be transitive.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth Lipschitz function (bounded if needed), and $W_t$ a $3$-dimentional Brownian motion. Consider the SDE on $\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb S^2$ (where $\mathbb S^2$ is the sphere).

\begin{cases}
\mathrm{d}X_t = f(X_t) \mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d} W_t\\
\mathrm{d}s_t = \mathrm{d}f(X_t) s_t - \langle s_t, \mathrm{d}f(X_t) s_t \rangle s_t \mathrm{d}t,
\end{cases}
where $\mathrm{d}f(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

I would like to know is there any condition on $f,$ which makes the above SDE, transitive on $B(0,1) \times \mathbb{S}^2$ (where $B(0,1)$ is the ball of radius $1$ centered in $0$), in the following sense: For every $(x,\theta)\in B(0,1)\times \mathbb S^2$ and open set $U\subset B(0,1)\times \mathbb S^2,$ there exists $t= t(x,\theta,U)$ such that
$$\mathbb E\left[\mathbb 1_U (X_t,s_t) \mid (X_0,s_0)= (x,\theta)\right] >0$$

So far, I was not able to figure what condition would imply this property. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an easy question at all! You might want to find, for a fixed set $U$ and a point $(x,\theta)$, a differential equation that is satisfied by the function $g(t) = \mathbb E[1_U(X_t,s_t) | (X_0,s_0) = (x,\theta)]$. This differential equation, as far as I know for really simple models, can end up having nice properties like a maximum principle or a boundary principle associated to it. I think that's how, for example we investigate Green function bounds and so on for simple models like the Brownian motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to simply prove the existence of a density with respect to Lebesgue measure because that will show

$$P[X_{t}\in U]=\int_{U} g_{X_{t}}dx>0.$$

This is a stronger result than what you ask but close.

A main approach is using the Hörmander theorem. So here one studies a corresponding control problem. By writing your SDE in Stratononich form

\begin{align*}
dY_t &= b(Y_t) dt + \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(Y_t) \circ dW_t^j
\end{align*}

for some appropriate vectors $b,\sigma$ in terms of your $df$, to prove that its density is strictly positive, it suffices to show: for all $x \in M=\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb S^2$, $t>0$ and for some $s \in (0,t)$ the following set fills up $M$ $$
A(s,x):=\{ y_s(u) : u \in H^1((0,\infty), \mathbb{R}^k) \}
$$ where $y_s(u)$ satisfies the associated control problem
$$
\dot{y_s}=b(y_s)+\sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(y_s) \dot{u_j}(s)\;, \quad y_0=x\;. $$
These results (and much more) are neatly described (on flat spaces) in Section 3.3 of [Michel and Pardoux 1990](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/etienne.pardoux/_media/en:michelpardoux_calculmalliavin.pdf).

In Nualart's related topics Theorem 2.3.1 he shows the existence of a density for the Lipschitz case in the Ito-formulation. If you only care about compact domains, see the article " "Smoothness and asymptotic estimates of densities for SDEs with locally smooth coefficients and applications to square root-type diffusions."